How to increase the number of requests received from chrome.devtools.network.Request.getContent (function)?
I have this code in devtools.js:
// calling this code for events
chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(
  async (harLog) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < harLog.entires.length; i++) {
      harLog.entires[i].body = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        harLog.entires[i].getContent((content, encoding) => {
          resolve(content)
        })
      });
    }
    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(`console.log( ${JSON.stringify(harLog)} )`);
    // processing harLog
  }
)

And if I call this code before updating the page (opened devtools), then everything works correctly, I can make endless requests, but if I reload the page (with open devtools), then the number of times I can call .getContent() decreases to 100 requests, and as it seemed to me, even these requests do not return content correctly, and then (after 100 requests) the code after calling .getContent() stops working, it just doesn't start, I did not find any errors using trycatch
If I reload the page again, then after each page reload there will be a maximum of 100 getContent() requests, but there are many more elements in harLog.entires.
I tried outputting each step to the console, and still the code stops working after .getContent()
also, if I close, and open devtools, the number of requests becomes infinite, but harLog is cleared, and harLog.entries.length === 0 (if I don't close-open devtools, then after reloading the page the harLog history remains)
I want the harLog to be saved, and to be able to call .getContent() as many times as I want

There's no way, and it's a bug. P.S. entires should be entries.
